# How to open Google Drive offline? (I.e. where is the Google Drive app icon?)

Tags: google-drive

I want to open Google Drive on my android tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S SM-T700), and I want to do this while I'm offline, as opposed to accessing my drive through Chrome.  (IOW, I want to access the items I have configured for offline access.)

I can't find its icon

[image]

...among the other app icons, nor anywhere else.  Also, I can't find any folder called "My Drive" in the tablet's storage.

(FWIW, I have rebooted the tablet, just in case.)

The Google Drive app is definitely installed (it shows up under Settings > Applications > Downloaded) and up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to find the widget?

Google Drive has a widget which looks like a mini version of the Google Search Bar. It includes the main function to access Drive, another button for uploads ('Save to Drive'), a camera icon which I assume saves to Google Photos, and the '+' icon to create objects like folders, new Google Docs, etc.

I have this on my home screen as opposed to the normal Drive icon, though I also have that at my disposal.
[image]
In this image its in the top right slot.